# Flask-SQLALchemy Unit Test Problems

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, python-unittest

I'm writing a web app by imitating [The Flask Mega-Tutorial](http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-vii-unit-testing).

As I was trying to add some unit test cases to my code. I found that the test cases in the Tutorial had many duplicated codes.

Here is the code segments:

```
def test_avatar(self):
    u = User(nickname='john', email='john@example.com')
    avatar = u.avatar(128)
    expected = 'http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/d4c74594d841139328695756648b6bd6'
    ...

def test_make_unique_nickname(self):
    u = User(nickname='john', email='john@example.com')
    db.session.add(u)
    db.session.commit()
    ...
```

The problem is that every time I want to test a new case I have to repeat this process：

```
u = User(nickname='john', email='john@example.com')
db.session.add(u)
db.session.commit()
```

So, I moved this process out and made it like this:

```
import unittest

from config import basedir
from app import app, db
from app.models import User

u = User(nickname='john', email='john@example.com')  # I put this out because some cases may want to use this stuff.

def _init_database():
    db.session.add(u)
    db.session.commit(u)

class TestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        app.config['TESTING'] = True
        app.config['WTF_CSRF_ENABLED'] = False
        app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///:memory:')
        self.app = app.test_client()
        db.create_all()
        _init_database()  # init database every time

    def tearDown(self):
        db.session.remove()
        db.drop_all()

    def test_case_1(self):
        self.assertTrue(User.query.count() == 1)  # case 1

    def test_case_2(self):
        self.assertTrue(User.query.count() == 1)  # case 1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

As you can see, two test cases are the same. However, **only one case can pass. the other one will fail**.

But if I move `u = User(nickname='john', email='john@example.com')` into `_init_database()`:

```
def _init_database():
    u = User(nickname='john', email='john@example.com')
    db.session.add(u)
    db.session.commit(u)
```

every thing is fine now.

I really don't know why! Could you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `User` instance is an object that is controlled by the ORM, so it is not a good idea to make it a global variable. That object not only contains your data but also includes database information. By making it global you are using it first on the database for the first test, then on the database for the second test.

A better approach is to create a new `User` instance for each test, and return it in your `setUp()` method:

```
def _init_database():
    u = User(nickname='john', email='john@example.com')
    db.session.add(u)
    db.session.commit()
    return u
```

Then you can attach this user to your test case and access it from your tests.

Comment: You mean I shouldn't use global variables. But, what if I want to use more than one User? Then, I have to return like this `return (u1, u2, u3)`? I can only think one way to solve it. Just make all these users Object Variables. But, every time I want to use a user I have to use like this `self.u1` which is a little ugly.

Comment: I wasn't trying to preach to you about how bad global variables are, sorry if it seemed that way. Global variables are useful sometimes, but in this case are problematic, because user models are somewhat magical, as they store database metadata that is controlled by SQLAlchemy. I would make your `_init_database()` function a method in the `TestCase` class, and I would store all the users as object variables. Then create a `_get_users()` method that returns your three users and call it as `u1, u2, u3 = self._get_users()` at the start of your test, so that you don't have to use `self.u1`.